# How to change the font on a button? nothing I try will work

Tags: java, swing, button, fonts, jpanel

I'm loading a custom font that is saved in the project folder as a ttf file. I get no errors when loading the font and when I print call the toString() method on plainFont it shows.                                                                                                  [family=PT Sans,name=PT Sans Bold,style=plain,size=12]

```
private static Font plainFont;
private static Font boldFont;
private final JPanel openingScreen;
private final JPanel monthlyScreen;
private final JPanel addAOTMScreen;
private final JPanel viewAOTMScreen;
private final JPanel viewPortScreen;
private final JPanel screens = new JPanel(new CardLayout());
private final JScrollPane scrollPane;    

/**
 * Tracks various music related things, including an artist of the month    tracker
 *
 * @author Matt Babel
 */
public MusicDatabase() {
    setTitle("Music Database");
    setLocation(400, 150);
    setSize(500, 400);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setResizable(false);
    setVisible(true);

    File fontFile = new File ("PT_Sans-Web-Bold.ttf");
    Font font = null;
    try {
        font = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, fontFile);
        font = font.deriveFont(Font.PLAIN, 12);
    } catch (FontFormatException e) {
        System.err.println("Font is null");
        System.exit(1);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println("Font is null");
        System.exit(1);
    }

    plainFont = font;
    System.out.println(plainFont);

    openingScreen = new JPanel();
    monthlyScreen = new JPanel();
    viewAOTMScreen = new JPanel();
    addAOTMScreen = new JPanel();

    viewPortScreen = new JPanel();
    viewPortScreen.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
    scrollPane.getViewport().add(viewAOTMScreen);
    scrollPane.getViewport().setBackground(backgroundColor);
    viewPortScreen.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    createOpeningScreen();

    screens.add(openingScreen, "Opening Screen");
    screens.add(monthlyScreen, "Monthly Screen");
    screens.add(viewPortScreen, "View Screen");
    screens.add(addAOTMScreen, "Add Screen");
    add(screens);

    CardLayout cardlayout = (CardLayout) screens.getLayout();
    cardlayout.show(screens, "Opening Screen");
}
```

I use the setFont() method on monthlyButton but when the program starts the buttons text is the still the default text. I have no idea why this is happening.

```
/**
 * initializes the opening screen
 */
public void createOpeningScreen() {
    openingScreen.setBackground(backgroundColor);
    openingScreen.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());   

    Button monthlyButton = new Button("Artists of the Month");
    System.out.println(plainFont);
    monthlyButton.setFont(plainFont);
    monthlyButton.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(150, 150));
    monthlyButton.addActionListener((java.awt.event.ActionEvent e) -> {
        if (!monthlyScreenOn) {
            createMonthlyScreen();
            monthlyScreenOn = true;
        }
        CardLayout cardLayout = (CardLayout) screens.getLayout();
        cardLayout.show(screens, "Monthly Screen");
        });

   GridBagConstraints a = new GridBagConstraints();

   a.gridx = 0;
   a.gridy = 0;
   a.weightx = .5;
   a.weighty = .5;
   openingScreen.setFont(plainFont);
   openingScreen.add(monthlyButton, a);
}
```

Comment: Don't use `java.awt.Button`, consider using `javax.swing.JButton` instead

Comment: [Should I avoid the use of set(Preferred|Maximum|Minimum)Size methods in Java Swing?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7229226/should-i-avoid-the-use-of-setpreferredmaximumminimumsize-methods-in-java-swi). Make use of the `JButton`'s `margin` properties or the `GridBagConstraints` `ipadx` and `ipady` properties

Comment: Changing the Button to a JButton worked, thanks for the help.